# Is intuitionistic naive set theory consistent?

Tags: set-theory, constructive-mathematics

I'm asking because the usual argument that a set either belongs in itself or not doesn't apply. I did a quick search and it appears that the logic is also required to be contraction free. If it's inconsistent, in very broad terms, what is the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full comprehension is intuitionistically inconsistent. Suppose $R$ is a set such that 
$$x \in R \leftrightarrow x \notin x$$
for all sets $x$. Then,
$$R \in R \leftrightarrow R \notin R$$
so we have an instance of a closed formula $\phi$ such that $\phi \leftrightarrow \lnot \phi$. *This* is the problem.

Indeed, given $\phi \to \lnot \phi$, it is easy to deduce that $\phi \to \bot$, i.e. $\lnot \phi$. But if we assume $\lnot \phi \to \phi$ as well, then we get $\phi$ by modus ponens. Thus, we have both $\lnot \phi$ and $\phi$ – a contradiction.

Comment: This is very cool, though. It means that if we can formulate a sensible logic in which $\phi \leftrightarrow \neg\phi$ isn't an outright contradiction, then naive set might just be consistent under that viewpoint.

Comment: The argument also goes through in [minimal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_logic), because we don't use _ex falso quodlibet_. The only way out seems to be paraconsistent logic.

Comment: I thought that was the whole point  That p -> ~p means ~p, That ~p -> p means p & ~p.  So formalistically there is a contradiction.  But you cannot get from both of those together to the 'bottom' state that implies everything, you can only get to places where it is problematic to talk about p.  If negation is only partially applicable, proving a single contradiction does not blow up your whole logic.